# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration for maven-plugin-plugin in m2e 1.5.x / Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, m2e, eclipse-luna

After upgrading to Eclipse Luna or to m2e 1.5.x and opening an existing workspace with Maven plugin projects, Eclipse complains that

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin ...
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to tell m2eclipse how to treat the plugin execution.

If the message is for instance:
    `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor`

Use following snippet:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[3.2,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>descriptor</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: No need to pollute your POMs any longer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65515389/1744774.

Comment: Seems great. I'm not on Eclipse anymore so cannot check that it works. Thanks for sharing though.

Answer (score 5):

Until version [1.4.x](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/m2e/m2e-core/+/m2e-1.4.x/org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml), the maven-plugin-plugin was covered by the default lifecycle mapping that ships with m2e.

Since version [1.5.x](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/m2e/m2e-core/+/m2e-1.5.x/org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml), the m2e default lifecycle mapping no longer covers the maven-plugin-plugin.

To get support for the maven-plugin-plugin with m2e version 1.5.x, install the new [Maven Development Tools](https://github.com/ifedorenko/com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev) plugins.

You may notice this problem after upgrading to Eclipse Luna because it ships with 1.5.x by default.

Comment: I'd installed Maven Development Tools plugins, but the error does not disappear

Comment: No need for an extra tool any longer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65515389/1744774.

Answer (score 5):

You can also configure eclipse to ignore or only warn for this issue.

[image]

Comment: No need to ignore these markers any longer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65515389/1744774.

Answer (score 1):

For those who come here with newer Eclipse versions (2020-12 at time of this writing).

There's a M2Eclipse page [Execution Not Covered](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html) with the following section:

> **Eclipse 4.2 Adds Default Mapping**
>
> If you are using Eclipse [...] and have troubles with mapping and won’t put mess into your `pom.xml` create a new file `lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml` and configure it in *Windows* → *Preferences* → *Maven* → *Lifecycle Mappings* (don’t forget to press <kbd>Reload workspace lifecycle mappings metadata</kbd> after each change of this file!).

[Corrections and formatting by me.]

#### For the `maven-plugin-plugin`

1. Add the following to `lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml`:

   ```xml
        <pluginExecution>
            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[0,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                    <goal>descriptor</goal>
                    <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                </goals>
            </pluginExecutionFilter>
            <action>
                <ignore />
            </action>
        </pluginExecution>
   ```
2. <kbd>Reload workspace lifecycle mappings metadata</kbd>
3. Right-click project → *Maven* → *Update Project...* or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
4. See the Markers with *Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: ...* disappearing.
5. Upvote this answer. :)

See also [the bountied answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30796733/1744774) to *How can I map Maven lifecycle phases not covered by the Eclipse m2e plugin?*.

Comment: In general, the problem with this approach is that you may want to set the action differently for different projects. E.g. in some projects you may want to execute a plugin, in others you may want to ignore it. Another problem is that your colleagues will have to repeat the process on their machines. If the settings are kept in the POM as suggested by a different answer here, all co-workers profit.

Comment: @rec You're right. I don't have co-workers here at home, however. :)