# Missing "Lifecycle mappings" menu

Tags: eclipse, maven, user-interface

As I get this popular error while using Maven plugin for Eclipse (m2e) :

`maven-dependency-plugin (goals "copy-dependencies", "unpack") is not supported by m2e.`

I tried fixing it with [Eclipse workspace lifecycle mapping metadata](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html#eclipse-workspace-lifecycle-mapping-metadata) as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30796733/5052399) but it turns out I don't have the LifecycleMappings submenu, my Window > Preferences > Maven only shows the following :

- Archetypes
- Discovery
- Installations
- Templates
- UI
- user Settings

Do I need a particular install step, or Eclipse version, or m2e version for this ?

Current :

> Eclipse Platform \ Version: 3.8.1 \ Build id: debbuild
>
> m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse - 1.0.200.20111228-1245
>
> m2e - slf4j over logback logging -    1.0.200.20111228-1245

Comment: You are using a _very old_ Eclipse version. Maybe that's the problem. Latest is 4.5.1 (Mars).

Comment: Switched to mars, problem solved. Thanks.